# JWT token authentication issue in Dot net core api. Giving Status Code: 401; Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

In angular application, calling .Net Core api using JWT token based Authentication.
Passing valid token with request header to .Net Core api, but its showing unauthorized request. but same code is working for other Domain name. even though it was working 3 days back.
When I am making request to other Action Method in different Controller in same API. its working fine.

Why same JWT token valid for one end point and invalid for other end point.
Showing **Status Code: 401; Unauthorized**  error.

[image]

Please suggest what is causing this issue. and how it can be fixed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure, that token is valid? How did you check it?

Comment: Could you please share the server's startup.cs codes which is related with JWT authentication? I guess you may have some special settings for the domain.

Comment: Are you using any kind of policy ?